# How can I import CSV UTF-8 file with Chinese characters into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, csv, utf-8

I've tried importing the following CSV file with UTF-8 encoding into MySQL, but the Chinese characters are not correctly populating. I also changed the column collate to utf8 - default collation and big5-big5_chinese_ci , but the data is still not populating the correct characters.

**Data I'm trying to import:**
[Data I'm trying to import into MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCw0O.jpg)

**SQL Query I'm using to import data:**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\Ulises.Sotomoyor\\Downloads\\Insights.csv' 
INTO TABLE unpaid_media.insights
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@Date, Section, Language, Insights)
SET Date = str_to_date(@Date, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

**MySQL Table Setting/Collation:**
[MySQL Table Setting/Collation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hB48.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify (at least) two things:

- The character encoding of the data coming in. -- Do this explicitly by adding `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` (or `big5`) in the `LOAD DATA` statement.
- The `CHARACTER SET` for the column -- It can be either `big5` or `utf8mb4`.  This does not have to match the `LOAD`.

In general, MySQL users should aim for `utf8mb4` throughout, but `big5` is OK.

The collation does not matter when inserting unless you have a uniqueness constraint.  (It does not seem that you have such.)

If you say the data has one encoding (eg, big5), but the column is in a different encoding (eg, utf8mb4), MySQL will convert as you do the inserting.

You may end up with other troubles.  See "Best practice" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored .  It is aimed at utf8, but it can be modified to import big5 and/or display in big5.

If you run into more troubles, please try to get the hex of the strings/columns in question.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. I'm pretty excited considering this was my first Stack Overflow post.

Answer (score 2):

Query used for the solution:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\Ulises.Sotomoyor\\Downloads\\Insights.csv'
     INTO TABLE unpaid_media.insights
     CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
     ENCLOSED BY '"' 
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
     IGNORE 1 LINES
     (@Date, Section, Language, Insights)
     SET Date = str_to_date(@Date, '%m/%d/%Y')
```