# MySQL JSON import but with 0 record

Tags: sql, mysql, json, import

Background:

1. I need to import Japanese characters into MySQL, so I can only use CSV utf-8, which does not get imported to MySQL. So that is why I resorted to JSON.
2. I tried LOAD DATA with CSV utf-8 file, but also does not work as I need to provide the base table - table has 100+ columns. I cannot map them all.

Problem: When I use Import wizard, I can see in the preview that the JSON is parsed correctly - as in I see all the correct japanese characters and numbers in the title as well as the values.

However, when I actually click import, it tells me that 0 record is imported and the table is empty except for the column name row...

I am sorry I cannot share the file due to company confidentiality.

Comment: *I can only use CSV utf-8, which does not get imported to MySQL. ... I tried LOAD DATA with CSV utf-8 file, but also does not work as I need to provide the base table - table has 100+ columns. I cannot map them all.* ?? Why? Probably, you are somehow doing the import incorrectly. *However, when I actually click import* Import the data using SQL query, not wizard. Specify all available options correctly in the query.

Comment: I actually made it work. I did forget to add the time when I import it using LOAD DATA and INTO TABLE, it requires a table with the correct columns, which means, I have to make 100+ columns manually, which is, while not unfeasible, not desirable. Anyways, I found out I can do the following - in the answer section

Answer (score 0):

If I do LOAD DATA INFILE + INTO TABLE command, it would throw me an error along the lines of "no such table defined," which is a common sense. So I need to define a Table first. Here is what I did.

1. Use Python to extract all the column names out of the CSV file. Make sure then to process the names so that it does not have any spaces in them, nor they are several lines. I had to use .replace(' ','') and .replace('\n','') to achieve them.
2. Take the modify columns names and replace the original Dataframe column names with it, so that they are SQL compatible -  no spaces, no several lines, etc.
3. Use LOAD DATA and other parameters such as FIELDS TERMINATED BY, ENCLOSED BY.
4. When importing CSV, make sure that CSV is in utf-8, or the Japanese/Chinese character will be broken.
5. Use CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 to import utf8. [the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446502/how-can-i-import-csv-utf-8-file-with-chinese-characters-into-mysql)